# ORA-03111 error on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in Entity Framework that receives an input (string) and an output (ref_cursor):

```
public virtual List<UserCost> GET_USER_CUSTO(string p_ANOMES)
{
    var p_ANOMESParameter = new OracleParameter("P_ANOMES", OracleDbType.Varchar2, p_ANOMES, ParameterDirection.Input);
    var p_refCursor = new OracleParameter("USER_CUSTO", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);

    return this.Database.SqlQuery<UserCost>(
                        "BEGIN TIM_FUNCTIONS.GET_TIM_USER_CUSTO(:P_ANOMES, :USER_CUSTO); end;", p_ANOMESParameter, p_refCursor).ToList();
}
```

But I keep getting this exception:

> ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel

I read that could be a problem with DB/dll versions but I already did the same to 2 other stored procedures and everything works fine. So I guess this is not the case.

This question was asked on the Oracle Forum with some helpful replies but no solution:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3967933

Comment: As I referred, I managed to execute and retrieve data from other stored procedures without problem. And the DB version is 11.2

Comment: Do you receive the error immediately or only after a a minute or so?

Comment: Firewall configuration maybe ? I encountered similar errors once because a firewall broke the connections. Solved it by adding parameters in the connection string (Connection Lifetime and/or Validate Connection)

Comment: Actually I think it's not related to entity framework and probably is not related to entity framework provider but it's related to Ado.Net provider. You could start trying to understand if the same stored procedure works without EF. I mean you can run the stored procedure with ado.net and, very important, read all the data (for example Console.Writeline every column or, a similar thing is to fill a datatable but in this case if Oracle/Ado.Net provider hangs on a particular record you won't see it).

Comment: With ADO.Net I had the same exception. Turns out the problem was in the SP itself. It was a TO_NUMBER function was getting me this error. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: I added an answer to help you spend your 50 points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think it's not related to entity framework and probably is not related to entity framework provider but it's related to Ado.Net provider.
You could start trying to understand if the same stored procedure works without EF.
I mean you can run the stored procedure with ado.net and, very important, read all the data (for example Console.Writeline every column or, a similar thing is to fill a datatable but in this case if Oracle/Ado.Net provider hangs on a particular record you won't see it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you are facing and it turns out for me to be an issue with my network not with the entity framework. Quoting an article that was very helpful to me, he instruct to try 4 steps:

> - First make sure that your query can be completed within the timeout that you have specified. If you consistently face this exception, try increasing your timeout.
> - That might help to get rid of the exception, but not the root cause. The root cause usually is a database that is not optimized for the query that you are executing or a bad network.
> - To find out if its the database that is the issue, try executing the same query in a host closer to the network. Or try executing the same query hitting the database from a different network. If you are convinced the database is the issue, try to tune it.
> - To find if it is the network that is having the issue, try to do a tcpdump and analyze if there are any out of order deliver of packets. Or dropped packets. If yes, then try to fix the network.

[Source here](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/mysterious-ora-03111-error.html)